# While - During - On - While in

Tags: grammar

Which of the following is the most suitable to replace the blank space?

(During - While - On - While in) questioning, the policeman did punitive actions to get the accused admitting.

Questioning is here an uncountable noun.
I suggest the last choice, but I want to assure what the best choice is.

Answer (score 1):

The word "*questioning*" here describes a process, and so it naturally fits with "during". "While in" is also possible, but in my view  not as likely.  But in any case the example is poorly written, because "*admitting*" requires a noun after it to indicate what the accused admitted. One possibility would be:

> During questioning, the policeman did punitive actions to get the accused admitting the crime.

Also "*punitive actions*" is an oddly euphemistic phrase. It would be better writing to indicate more exactly what the policeman did. For example:

> During questioning, the policeman punched the accused to get the accused to admit to the crime.

Answer (score 0):

Side note: There are several unrelated problems with your sample sentence.

1. We don't say "did punitive actions". You could say "did punitive things" or "took punitive actions".
2. In any case, "punitive" doesn't make sense her. "Punitive" means "having to do with punishment". But in context, the policeman is not punishing the suspect for a crime. He is trying to force him to confess to a crime. For example, if you sue someone, the court may award "compensatory damages", money to "compensate" you for actual losses that you suffered, and also "punitive damages", money to push the defendant for abusing you. Like if someone cheated you out of $1000, the court may order him to give you back the $1000, and then also give you another, say, $2000 to punish him for cheating you.

In context, it would make more sense to say, perhaps, "engaged in abusive actions", or more simply, "abused the suspect" or "was abusive". Or "used harsh treatment", or if you want to be extreme, "tortured the suspect".

3. You shift tenses between "did" and "admitting". To be consistent you should say something more like "... used harsh tactics to get the suspect to admit to the crime". Or more commonly, we'd say "... get the suspect to confess."

All that said, to your actual question ...

"During" is valid. "Questioning" is an event, the word is being used as a noun here. (It's a gerund, to be more specific.) So something can happen "during" this event.

"While questioning" is at best awkward. In that case you're using "questioning" as a verb, but it really calls for an object. Questioning who or what? You could say, "While questioning THE SUSPECT, the policeman ..."

"On questioning" isn't valid. Or at least is not something that native speakers say. I suppose "on" is sometimes used with a noun for an event to mean when it happened, like, "On arrival, you must fill out an immigration form", or "On completion of the program, you will be given a certificate." But I don't think I've ever heard someone say "On questioning ..."

"While in questioning" doesn't work because that phrase is normally understood to refer to the person being questioned, not the person doing the questioning. You could say, "While in questioning, the suspect confessed." But you can't say, "While in questioning, the policeman beat up the suspect", because the policeman is not the one who is in questioning.